# Spring Boot: Load nested properties in application.yml as java.util.Properties object

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

My application.yml:

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: myhost.com
    port: 123
    username: my@mail.com
    password: mypassword
    properties:
      mail:
        transport:
          protocol: smtp
      debug: true
      smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls:
          enable: true
          required: true
        localhost: mylocalhost.com
```

What I want to "automate":

```
@Configuration
class MailConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    fun getMailSender(): JavaMailSender {
        return JavaMailSenderImpl().apply {
            host = "myhost.com"
            port = 123
            username = "my@mail.com"
            password = "mypassword"
            javaMailProperties["mail.transport.protocol"] = "smtp"
            javaMailProperties["mail.smtp.auth"] = "true"
            javaMailProperties["mail.smtp.starttls.enable"] = "true"
            javaMailProperties["mail.smtp.localhost"] = "mylocalhost.com"
            javaMailProperties["mail.smtp.starttls.required"] = "true"
            javaMailProperties["mail.debug"] = "true"
        }
    }
}
```

The `javaMailProperties`-attribute of `JavaMailSenderImpl` is of type `java.util.Properties`.

I already saw that I can access the first four properties via `@ConfigurationProperties(value = "spring.mail")` on the bean method. This will ignore `spring.mail.properties` since there is no `setProperties`-method on `JavaMailSender` (not completely clean but okay).

The main problem is how to get the nested properties under `spring.mail.properties` as `java.util.Properties`-object in order to initialize the `javaMailProperties`-attribute of `JavaMailSenderImpl`. How can I reach this in a clean way?

Thanks in advance.